# How do I set up an NSPredicate to check a relationship's attribute?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have an entity called `Entry`, which has a one-to-many relationship with an entity called `Media`. The relationship name, from the `Media` side, is `entry`. Entry has an attribute named `entryID`, and I want to create a NSPredicate on media entities which returns all where their `entry` relationship has a particular `entryID`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the relationship you want to fetch is called `entry` and `entryID` is some kind of number type.

```
NSNumber *desiredID = @(12345);
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"entry.entryID = %@", desiredID];
```